# Piecewise holomorphic map and complex submanifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, singularity

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $Y\subset X$ a compact complex submanifold of codimension $1$. Let $f:X\to Z$ be a continuous map such that $f|_{X\setminus Y}$ is biholomorphic and $f|_Y$ is constant/holomorphic.

Is $f$ holomorphic under this conditions? If not, what is a suitable criterion to check?

This question came up in the context of resolution of singularites, so $Y$ can be thought of as an exeptional divisor and I want to check that $f$ is a resolution of singularities/bimeromorphic.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that some form of the Hartogs's Extension theorem is valid in this setting: in general holomorphic function of several variables defined on "well behaved sets" cannot have compact singularities. This is also the case when $X$ is a complex analytic set and $Y$ one of its subset, provided both $X$  and $Y$ satisfy some technical conditions (Andreotti and other proved theorems of such kind).

Comment: @DanieleTampieri: I thought about it for a while: I think because codim $Y>0$, every continuous exension of $f|_{X\setminus Y}$ agrees, and by Hartog's, we know that a continuous extension exists, which is also holomorphic. Would you agree on this?

Comment: Exactly: from my naive point of view $\mathrm{codim} Y>0$ implies you can "enclose $Y$" inside a ball $B$ such that $\partial B\Subset X\setminus Y$. Then, by using $f|_{\partial{B}}$ and the Martinelli-Bochner-Koppelman formula extend holomorphically $f$ inside $B$ ([this is one of the methods used to prove Hartogs's extension theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928718/a-function-holomorphic-on-all-of-mathbbcn-cannot-have-a-nonempty-bounded-s/2929345#2929345))